How to get one-line commit info when using `git log -L`
git log -L:function_name:file_name can be used to get the log of all commits that touched a specific function. But it always shows the content/diff of the commit as if -p option was applied.
I have tried to several different options to the command like --oneline, --abbrev-commit, -U0 but they just remove a few lines and still print a lot of commit content.
How can I get a one-line summary?

It "Implies --patch."

My guess is people downvoted for lack of research, since this is quite clearly stated in the doc. Not a lot you can do now, I'am afraid. (For what it's worth, well I did not. I have downvoted questions in the past for this reason, but only when associated to other negative factors, and yours is otherwise clear and overall fine)

As indicated in the doc, only --no-patch achieves what you want. Other diff format options are disabled with -L

Implies --patch. Patch output can be suppressed using --no-patch, but other diff formats (namely --raw, --numstat, --shortstat, --dirstat, --summary, --name-only, --name-status, --check) are not currently implemented.


Other diff format options are disabled, but e.g. --no-patch --oneline would work.

@jonrsharpe Thanks for the formatting edit. And yes about diff format options, that's what I meant, but it was unclear. I had tested it with --oneline and it works indeed.

Thanks, git log --no-patch --oneline -L:function_name:file_name  works great.
